# Read text and save some information in Java

Tags: java, file, arraylist, split

I have a text formatted as follow:

```
Lorem ipsum word <tag> 1,2,3,4 </tag> dolor sit amen
```

How can I save only "1,2,3,4" in an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Is this a full XML-valid syntax text or it is a plain text that may contain `<tag>Content</tag>`?

Comment: I assume you want a `List<Integer>` with four separate entries, but your question could be interpreted as asking for a `List<String>` with one entry whose value is `"1,2,3,4"`.

Comment: It's a file .kml and i would parse it.

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm? You need the values between the tags?

Comment: Exactly! I need the value between the tags..How can i do to obtain them rapidly?

Comment: Since it is a XML file it would be better to use a XML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something you can start with:

```
    String str="Lorem ipsum word <tag> 1,2,3,4 </tag> dolor sit amen";
    String tag=str.substring(str.indexOf("<tag>") + "<tag>".length());
    tag = tag.substring(0, tag.indexOf("</tag>")).trim();

    String[] ints = tag.split(",");

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (String s : ints) {
        list.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
    }
    System.out.println(list);
```

Note that this code does not handle any errors nor does it check if the input string is valid.